# How to reference cells in another sheet based on multiple conditions

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am working on converting an edge list to an adjacency matrix and am looking for a function in LibreOffice Calc to reference cell values with a few conditions.

My table (in sheet2) looks like this:

```
     A (id) B (id) C (weight)   
1    002    003    4
2    003    005    2
3    001    003    1
4    002    004    5
5    004    001    3
```

I would like to make a new data set (in sheet1) like this, containing the value of column C (weight):

```
     A      B    C    D    E    F
1           001  002  003  004  005
2    001    0    0    1    0    0
3    002    0    0    4    5    0
4    003    0    0    0    0    2
5    004    3    0    0    0    0
```

So, e.g. in cell B2 I would like a function that works something like this:

=(the value of column C in sheet2 WHERE "*a row in column A in sheet2 equals the value of A2 in sheet1*" AND "*a row in column B in sheet 2 that equals B1 in sheet1*")

If no result it should produce the value "0".

Is there a way to make this function in LibreOffice Calc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Pivot Table, but i didn't find a way to fulfil every requirement. I'm sure there are better ways, so this is some sort of quick&dirty:

1. Select the "data columns" A to C (in your example: B1:D6)
2. Menu Data - Pivot Table -> from current selection
3. Drag the "A" column to "Row fields", "B" to "Column fields" and "C" to Data Fields. You may want to disable "Total Columns", "Total rows" and "Add filter" from <kbd>More</kbd> options:

   [image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

So, it has the correct values at correct places, but i didn't find a way to insert 0 values where's no combination result.

You can easily edit the resulting matrix or create a editable copy by `copy` / `paste special` (values and text).